# present an alertviewcontroller during segue

Tags: ios, swift

I have a helper method that prompts an alertviewcontroller on my actual view controller. however, if this happens during a segue. my segue gets cancelled. Any ideas?

```
    AlamoHelper.request(.POST, url: AppDelegate.kbaseUrl + "users/signin", parameters: ["email": String(emailTextField.text!), "password": String(passwordTextField.text!)])
        .responseJSON {
            response in
            switch (response.result) {
            case .Success:
                var json = JSON(response.result.value!)
                if (json["status"] != 200){
                    AppDelegate.removeCookies()
                    AppDelegate.isLoggedIn = false
                } else {
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showTabBarController", sender: self)
                    self.emailTextField.text = ""
                    self.passwordTextField.text = ""
                    self.appDelegate.storeCookies()
                    AppDelegate.isLoggedIn = true
                    self.addDeviceToken()
                }
                break

            case .Failure:
                break
            }
    }
```

in my helper, the part where I show the alert controller is this

```
    if json["status"].intValue == 500 {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Unknown error", message: "Please try again later. If problem persists, please contact Offpeak support", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
                    alert.addAction(okAction)

                    AlamoHelper.getCurrentViewController().presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
```

Comment: It would be relatively easy (but not very elegant) to give up presenting your alert if a segue is in progress, by setting up some sort of "segueIsInProgress" flag in `prepareForSegue` and clearing it in e.g. `viewDidAppear`. However, the real solution would be perhaps to be able to 'enqueue' your alert somewhere and present it once the segue completes, right?

Comment: I assume that your code has some sort of race condition, and the alert is only sometimes presented during the segue (when the timing happens to coincide)?

Comment: The reason I had this implementation is that, back when iOS 7 I've been using AlertView.show(), and the alertView shows while the segue is continuing. But now that this is an alertviewcontroller, presenting the alertviewcontroller kinda terminates the segue. Hence the question